# loading a graph from .meta file from Tensorflow in c++ for inference

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I have trained some models using tensorflow 1.5.1 and I have the checkpoints for those models (including .ckpt and .meta files). Now I want to do inference in c++ using those files.

In python, I would do the following to save and load the graph and the checkpoints.
for saving:

```
    images = tf.placeholder(...) // the input layer
    //the graph def
    output = tf.nn.softmax(net) // the output layer
    tf.add_to_collection('images', images)
    tf.add_to_collection('output', output)
```

for inference i restore the graph and the checkpoint then restore the input and output layers from collections like so:

```
    meta_file = './models/last-100.meta'
    ckpt_file = './models/last-100'
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_file)
        saver.restore(sess, ckpt_file)
        images = tf.get_collection('images')
        output = tf.get_collection('output')
        outputTensors = sess.run(output, feed_dict={images: np.array(an_image)})
```

now assuming that I did the saving in python as usual, how can I do inference and restore in c++ with simple code like in python?

I have found examples and tutorials but for tensorflow versions 0.7 0.12 and the same code doesn't work for version 1.5. I found no tutorials for restoring models using c++ API on tensorflow website.

Comment: See https://github.com/PatWie/tensorflow_inference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the sake of this [thread](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1644/please-dont-write-answers-in-comments). I will rephrase my comment into an answer.

Posting a full example would require either a CMake setup or putting the file into a specific directory to run bazel. As I do favor the first way and it would burst all limits on this post to cover all parts I would like to redirect to a [complete implementation in C99, C++, GO without Bazel](https://github.com/PatWie/tensorflow_inference) which I tested for TF > v1.5.

Loading a graph in C++ is not much more difficult than in Python, **given** you compiled TensorFlow already from source.

Start by creating a MWE, which creates a very dump network graph is always a good idea to figure out how things work:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 2], name='input')
output = tf.identity(tf.layers.dense(x, 1), name='output')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
    saver.save(sess, './exported/my_model')
```

There are probably tons of answers here on SO about this part. So I just let it stay here without further explanation.

## Loading in Python

Before doing stuff in other languages, we can try to do it in python properly -- in the sense: we just need to rewrite it in C++.
Even restoring is very easy in python like:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:

    # load the computation graph
    loader = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./exported/my_model.meta')
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    loader = loader.restore(sess, './exported/my_model')

    x = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('input:0')
    output = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('output:0')
```

it is not helpful as most of these API endpoints do not exists in the C++ API (yet?). An alternative version would be

```py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:

    metaGraph = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./exported/my_model.meta')
    restore_op_name = metaGraph.as_saver_def().restore_op_name
    restore_op = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name(restore_op_name)
    filename_tensor_name = metaGraph.as_saver_def().filename_tensor_name
    sess.run(restore_op, {filename_tensor_name: './exported/my_model'})


    x = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('input:0')
    output = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('output:0')
```

Hang on. You can always use `print(dir(object))` to get the properties like `restore_op_name`, ... .
Restoring a model is an operation in TensorFlow like every other operation. We just call this operation and providing the path (a string-tensor) as an input. We can even write our own `restore` operation

```py
def restore(sess, metaGraph, fn):
    restore_op_name = metaGraph.as_saver_def().restore_op_name   # u'save/restore_all'
    restore_op = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name(restore_op_name)
    filename_tensor_name = metaGraph.as_saver_def().filename_tensor_name  # u'save/Const'
    sess.run(restore_op, {filename_tensor_name: fn})
```

Even this looks strange, it now greatly helps to do the same stuff in C++.

## Loading in C++

Starting with the usual stuff

```cpp
#include <tensorflow/core/public/session.h>
#include <tensorflow/core/public/session_options.h>
#include <tensorflow/core/protobuf/meta_graph.pb.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::vector<std::pair<std::string, tensorflow::Tensor>> tensor_dict;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  const std::string graph_fn = "./exported/my_model.meta";
  const std::string checkpoint_fn = "./exported/my_model";

  // prepare session
  tensorflow::Session *sess;
  tensorflow::SessionOptions options;
  TF_CHECK_OK(tensorflow::NewSession(options, &sess));

  // here we will put our loading of the graph and weights

  return 0;
}
```

You should be able to compile this by either put it in the TensorFlow repo and use bazel or simply follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/PatWie/tensorflow_inference) to use CMake.

We need to create such a `meta_graph` created by `tf.train.import_meta_graph`. This can be done by

```cpp
tensorflow::MetaGraphDef graph_def;
TF_CHECK_OK(ReadBinaryProto(tensorflow::Env::Default(), graph_fn, &graph_def));
```

In C++ reading a graph from file is *not* the same as importing a graph in Python. We need to create this graph in a session by

```cpp
TF_CHECK_OK(sess->Create(graph_def.graph_def()));
```

By looking at the strange python `restore` function above:

```py
restore_op_name = metaGraph.as_saver_def().restore_op_name
restore_op = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name(restore_op_name)
filename_tensor_name = metaGraph.as_saver_def().filename_tensor_name
```

we can code the equivalent piece in C++

```cpp
const std::string restore_op_name = graph_def.saver_def().restore_op_name()
const std::string filename_tensor_name = graph_def.saver_def().filename_tensor_name()
```

Having this in place, we just run the operation by

```cpp
sess->Run(feed_dict,     // inputs
          {},            // output_tensor_names (we do not need them)
          {restore_op},  // target_node_names
          nullptr)       // outputs (there are no outputs this time)
```

Creating the feed_dict is probably a post on its own and this answer is already long enough. It does only cover the most important stuff. I would like to redirect to a [complete implementation in C99, C++, GO without Bazel](https://github.com/PatWie/tensorflow_inference) which I tested for TF > v1.5. This is not that hard -- it just can get very long in the case of the [plain C version](https://github.com/PatWie/tensorflow_inference/blob/master/inference/c/inference_c.c).

Comment: So to restore/save model, I have to call `session->Run()` in C++?

Comment: Just like you do in python.